# How to raise all elements less than 5 to the power of 2, greater than 5 - to the power of 3 Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to raise all elements less than 5 to the power of 2, greater than 5 - to the power of 3 using Numpy

Array:

```
arr = np.array([[0, 2, 4, 6],
               [7, 9, 11, 13],
               [14, 16, 18, 20],
               [21, 23, 25, 27]],
               dtype=np.uint64)
```

Answer (score 3):

In-place:

```
mask_a = x < 5
mask_b = x > 5

x[mask_a] **= 2
x[mask_b] **= 3
```

If you meant `mask_b = x >= 5`, you can also do:

```
x = np.where(x < 5, x**2, x**3)
```